# What's the mathematical formula for the sequence 3 6 12 18 30 42 66 90 ...?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What's the mathematical formula for the sequence 3 6 12 18 30 42 66 90 ... ?  I can provide more numbers if necessary but the pattern is that the first number is exponentially doubling every two steps.

Comment: Start at 0, then add 3, then add 3, then add 6, then add 6, then add 12 then add 12, then add 24, then add 24 etc...

Comment: https://oeis.org/A061776

Comment: @GitGud Just looking at oeis makes all the fun vanish

Comment: @Peter https://goo.gl/VRND7E

Comment: We have $$a_k=6\cdot 2^{k/2}-6$$ for even $k$

Comment: And $$a_k=9\cdot 2^{(k-1)/2}-6$$ for odd $k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general formula is $$a_n=(\frac{15}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\cdot (-1)^{n+1})\cdot 2^{\lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\rceil}-6$$

Comment: The brackets denote the "ceil"-function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help.  Using the links provided in the comments I was able to find the following formula
$y\ =\ 3\ \cdot2^{\frac{x-3}{2}}\left(\left(2\cdot\sqrt{2}-3\right)\cdot\left(-1\right)^{x}+3+2\sqrt{2}\right)-6$