# Is there a formula for the sequence of numbers 3-6-9-12-15-18-21-24-27-30-36-42-48-54-60-66-72-78-84-90-102-114-126-138-150 etc..?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The pattern to this sequence is that every 10 terms, the sequential differences doubles.

This sequence is a modified version of the sequence I asked about in this post: [What's the mathematical formula for the sequence 3 6 12 18 30 42 66 90 ...?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726899/whats-the-mathematical-formula-for-the-sequence-3-6-12-18-30-42-66-90)

The general formula for 3-6-12-18-30-42-66-90 is $$a_n=\left(\frac{15}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\cdot (-1)^{n+1}\right)\cdot 2^{\left\lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rceil}-6$$

However, the sequence 3-6-9-12-15-18-21-24-27-30-36-42-48-54-60-66-72-78-84-90-102-114-126-138-150 the sequential difference double every 10 terms instead of every 2 terms.

How could we adapt the formula above to support this new series of numbers?

Comment: You should make it clear that the pattern to this sequence is that every 10 terms, the sequential differences doubles. Without that, your question is ill-defined. As for pointers, have you considered replacing some of the 2's with 10?

Comment: Good point.  I've made the modification to the post.  I did try replacing the 2's with 10.  Basically, I multiplied the constants by a factor of 5.  The result was close but not right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by defining $a_0=0$ and note that $a_{10k}=10\cdot 3 + 10\cdot 6 + 10\cdot 12 + \ldots 10 \cdot 3\cdot 2^{k-1}=10\cdot 3 \cdot (2^k-1)$ and $a_{10k+m}=a_{10k}+m\cdot 3\cdot 2^k$ for $0 \le m \lt 10$ so

write $n=10k+m$ with $0 \le m \lt 10$ and
$$a_n=a_{10k+m}=30(2^k-1)+3m2^k$$

Comment: Are you sure that's right?  Using your second equation, with n =1, $a_n=3$ but with n =2, $a_n=9$

Comment: Damn. That power was meant to be just a multiplication. Sorry. $$\begin{array}{l} \text{That other seq.:} &a_n = (6+3(n \text{ mod } 2)) \cdot 2^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} -6,\\ \text{Ross Millikan:} &a_n = (30+3(n \text{ mod } 10)) \cdot 2^{\lfloor n/10 \rfloor} -30.\end{array}$$

Comment: Amazing.  That's bang on!  Thanks so much.